# Using maven ant plugin in javafx application, How to add Dependencies in javaFX jar. Still facing class not found exception

Tags: java, javafx-2, maven-3, executable-jar, maven-antrun-plugin

I using this guide added my dependencies to main jar [JavaFX jar with dependencies bundled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13361804/javafx-jar-with-dependencies-bundled)
i am facing dependencies issue which causing Class not found exception. My Pom is exactly like mentioned in above link. i use dependencies plugin to copy dependencies to lib folder in target.

Here is my stack trace

```
Try calling Class.forName(com.client.main.App) using classLoader = j
ava.net.URLClassLoader@3c9076d
found class: class com.client.main.App
launchApp: Try calling com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication

Autoconfig of proxy is completed.
JavaFX: using com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit
Exception in Application init method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
    at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(Unknown So
urce)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/inject/Module
    at com.nuaxis.rpas.client.main.App.init(App.java:25)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.Module
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
Done with invoke and wait
```

Maven Ant Task in maven pom file using maven ant plugin

```
<jfxjar destfile="${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}">
  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes" />
  <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/lib/" includes="*.jar" />    

  <application name="${project.name}" mainClass="com.client.main.App" />        
  <resources>
     <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/lib/" includes="*.jar" />
  </resources>
</jfxjar>
```

Here is my Fx Application Class code

```
public class App extends Application {
    /*public static Logger mLogger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(App.class);    */
public static Injector injector;
public static AppHandler mAppHandler;

@Override
public void init() throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
    injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceModule());/*This line cause exception*/
    mAppHandler = injector.getInstance(AppHandler.class);
    if(mAppHandler!=null)
        mAppHandler.startHandler();
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/FXMLDocument.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/styles/style.css");
    stage.setTitle("RPAS Java Client");
    stage.getIcons().add(new Image("/images/RPAS Java Client.png"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

@Override
public void stop() throws Exception {
    mAppHandler.stopHandler();
} 



/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) { 
    launch(args);        
}

}
```

Here is my understanding

Now what i understand is my dependencies are not properly loading. ant "jar making" task makes jar without any issues. when i double click it through exception. I opened the jar and here is my Manifest

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
JavaFX-Version: 2.2
JavaFX-Application-Class: com.client.main.App
JavaFX-Class-Path: guice-3.0.jar hamcrest-core-1.3.jar javax.inject-1.jar log4j-1.2.15.jar slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar slf4j-log4j12-1.7.7.jar 
Created-By: JavaFX Packager
Main-Class: com/javafx/main/Main
```

I also wonder when i saw that jar making process add com.javafx.main.Main.java file to the code automatically which first check Run time(JRE and FX) and then if all successful invoke the com.sun.javafx.Application.LauncherImp .

can any body help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had resolved the issue. see my final pom at this link [where should i put installer resources (wxs file,dmg-script,icon) and how to configure maven antrun when deploying self contained app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25973919/where-should-i-put-wix-resource-wxs-file-and-how-to-configure-fxpackager-when)